# Create JSON Object from two arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to create one Json object from the two arrays using JavaScript or jQuery. The data saved in database in the following format:

> clob_field_1: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 etc etc ...
>
> clob_field_2: 8106.23, 7856.49, 8009.15, 8121.78, 8082.8, 8294.43,
>   8137.9, 8265.81, 8319.5, 8186.43 etc etc ...

Ideally, the outcome should looks like this:

> [{"Item:" 1, "Value:" 8106.23}, {"Item:" 2, "Value:" 7856.49}, {"Item:" 3, "Value:" 8009.15}, {"Item:" 4, "Value:" 8121.78}, etc etc ...]

So what I've done, I've fetched the clobs fileds from the database using PL/SQL, so I can access it from the JavaScript. After that I declared 2 variables and set the object and want to loop through the data to create a nice pairs of data. This is my JavaScript code so far:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var b = [8106.23, 7856.49, 8009.15, 8121.78, 8082.8, 8294.43, 8137.9,    8265.81, 8319.5, 8186.43];
  var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  obj['Item:' + a[i]] = 'Value:' + b[i] + '}';
}
alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

But the outcome is awful and looks as follows:

```
{"Item:1":"Value:8106.23}","Item:2":"Value:7856.49}","Item:3":"Value:8009.15}","Item:4":"Value:8121.78}","Item:5":"Value:8082.8}","Item:6":"Value:8294.43}","Item:7":"Value:8137.9}","Item:8":"Value:8265.81}","Item:9":"Value:8319.5}","Item:10":"Value:8186.43}"}
```

The left curly brackets are missing from the pair 2 onwards, colons instead of coma, speech marks are in wrong place etc etc ... I believe there is a syntaxis error in my code and I cannot figure out what is it. Any help appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` why would you want something like that? Why not simply `var a = 10;`

Comment: In your code you have only the closing `+ '}'` why? I mean why do you use it at all?

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: You want an array in output and you just intiaized an object and that object is globally intialized for loop which is not a right justice with question

Comment: It's important that you realise that you should only care about building the list + objects. There is no reason for you to try and inject curly brackets or even colons into the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array for your output and push new objects into it rather than setting them all in a single object.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var b = [8106.23, 7856.49, 8009.15, 8121.78, 8082.8, 8294.43, 8137.9,    8265.81, 8319.5, 8186.43];
var output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    output.push({'Item': a[i], 'Value': b[i]});
}
alert(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Comment: Works as a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys, I will mark 'Kaivosukeltaja' answer as correct as it best suit to my requirements. But again, thanks to all of you, really appreciated your help guys ! And thanks for pointing me what was the problem with my code !

Answer (score 3):

A compact way via `map` and ES6 syntax:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var b = [8106.23, 7856.49, 8009.15, 8121.78, 8082.8, 8294.43, 8137.9, 8265.81, 
         8319.5, 8186.43];
var obj = a.map( (item, i) => ({ item, value: b[i] }) );
console.log(obj);
```

Note: I would advise against capitalising the first letter of property names. It is a common practice to only do this for constructor functions.

Comment: you could make it a bit more compact with `var obj = a.map((item, i) => ({ item, value: b[i] }));`

Comment: Thanks @NinaScholz, you are right. NB: I see we are often looking at the same questions :) I like your contributions!

Comment: The reason I keep it capital, that I'm gonna create a chart using this data and I have to keep capital. But thanks for your comments, will keep it my mind in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
var obj = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  obj.push({
     Item: a[i],
     Value: b[i]
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code works as well ! Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var b = [8106.23, 7856.49, 8009.15, 8121.78, 8082.8, 8294.43, 8137.9,    8265.81, 8319.5, 8186.43];

  var objArra = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   var obj = {};

  obj['Item:'] = a[i];
  obj['value:'] = b[i];
  objArra.push(obj)
}
alert(JSON.stringify(objArra));
```

[Fiddle Check](https://jsfiddle.net/eradi_singh/f2Lb9mqw/)

Comment: Thanks, that also works, but I marked 'Kaivosukeltaja' answer as correct as it best suit my requirements. Thanks for your help anyways and it was helpfull too !

Answer (score 1):

if you suppose, that your inputs will be right, you could also try this

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var b = [8106.23, 7856.49, 8009.15, 8121.78, 8082.8, 8294.43, 8137.9,    8265.81, 8319.5, 8186.43];
let sum = a.map((val, index) => {
    return {'Item':val, 'Value': b[index]};
})
```